# Doctrine 2.0 ready for use?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a small project (some mark tracking software for a school subject department - PHP frontend with a sqlite DB) and have decided to use ORM.

I've taken a look at RedBeanPHP but it seemed a bit too limited for my liking. As such, I've decided to give Doctrine a go.

My only prior experience with ORM is LINQ to SQL in .NET. Anyway, I was wondering if I should get started with Doctrine 2.0 (which is in beta at the moment) or if I should take sometime to learn 1.2.

I'm looking for feedback from those who are comfortable with both, and more importantly, I'd like to know how complete the Doctrine 2.0 documentation is. Is there enough information on the website for somebody new to Doctrine (and quite new to ORM) to get up and running with 2.0 or is the documentation for the new version still quite lacking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doctrine 2 is a DataMapper ORM whereas 1.2 is Active Record. I would go with 2.0; the documentation is great

Comment: +1 I've been using Doctrine 2 in production for quite some time now. It's great, and am really looking forward to the first full release.

Comment: Same here.  I've had no (major) issues with D2 (been using since alpha stages too).  The documentation and community are great and definitely worth the effort of learning.

Answer (score 4):

The Doctrine2 documentation is quite good already.  I'd start with the [reference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/en).

I've been developing with Doctrine2 for a few months now, and have had no issues.  I'll be going into production with it soon, and am pretty confident.

2.0's DataMapper pattern is really superior to the 1.2/ActiveRecord model.  Very flexible, and possible more performant.  If you're starting development today, I think it's very likely the best way to go.