# Doctrine where exact use 1.2 version and 2.0 Version?

Tags: php, doctrine

What is difference between Doctrine 1.2 and 2.0, how to choose between them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doctrine 2

- it's the recommendend version
- ships with symfony 2.0
- faster than 1.2
- no magic methods
- uses entity manager (datamapper like)
- components are loosely coupled
- requires PHP 5.3 (uses namespaces)
- relative new project

Doctrine 1.2

- easier to learn
- works with php < 5.3
- ships with symfony 1.3 / 1.4
- magic methods (ActiveRecord like)
- mature and tested project
- less typing

Doctrine 2.0

```
$user = new User;
$user->setName('Mr.Right');
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Doctrine 1.2

```
$user = new User;
$user->setName('Mr.Right');
$user->save();
```

To summarize, imho Doctrine 2.0 has a steeper learning curve even if it
performs better (clever use of transactions). I find ActiveRecord persistence model and magic methods rather clumsy so I'll go with the 2.0, but this is my personal opinion,
Doctrine 1.2 is still very good (expecially with small projects where the 2.0 could be overkill)

see also

[Doctrine 2.0 ready for use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074670/doctrine-2-0-ready-for-use)

[Datamapper vs ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169832/data-mapper-vs-active-record)

Comment: ok.thanku .in my old project we are using doctrine 1.0.7 just we updated to new version .which version is good for any code modifictions?any why?

Comment: the transition from 1.0 to 1.2 should be straightforward. to upgrade to 2.0 you will have to change a lot.

Comment: if i want change  2.0 .what major changes ?thanku for help...thanks alot.

Comment: schema syntax differs (yml/xml/php) so you have to rebuild your model and collection classes, moreover you must set up and use the entity manager to use the persistence layer (database interaction) and the query builders. i think about 70% of code will change. i suggest to stick with 1.2 for legacy code and use 2.0 only for new projects.

Comment: ok thanks alot.now i am changing from  1.0.7 to 1.2.4 version.what are the changes that as to be done ? in Config.

Comment: i am getting error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Exception' with message 'Couldn't find class GsName' in /var/www/